# Keeping track of open child dialogs

Tags: c++, winapi, parent-child, c++builder-xe2, window-messages

In a C++ program (embarcadero XE2, vcl) I would like to send window-messages from parent to all child windows.
For this, I registered a windowMessage, send the message with `PostMessage(handle,msg,wparam,lparam)` in a loop for all handles and receive it on each dialog with `WndProc(TMessage& Message)`.

My problem is to keep track of the open window handles. Since most dialogs are opened via `Show()`, multiple of them can run at the same time.

So far I used a `std::vector<HWND>` to store the Window-Handles. However, this would require me to keep track of which handle is still valid at a time.
I could solve this by adding a `onClose` Handler to the dialogs and call a procedure in the main thread with the dialog's handle as a parameter, so it can be removed from the vector...

Is there a nicer solution, like a self-updating list as in `Application.OpenForms` (.NET)? Or maybe a better way to notify child-dialog of an event from the main dialog?

Comment: [In Windows, dialog boxes are not *children*, they are *owned windows*.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100315-00/?p=14613)

Comment: This seems like a horrible use of a registered window message, which is best used when applications from different vendors are trying to communicate - probably via broadcast messages. An application sending its own windows messages would be far better served using the WM_USER or WM_APP defined ranges.

Comment: @andlabs Thanks for the comment! I wouldn't have been able to find out why Cody's solution wouldn't work if you didn't mention the difference between children and owned dialogs. ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A window already tracks its children internally, so you just need to tap into that. If you want to send a message to all of a window's child windows, then you just need to recursively iterate through all of that window's children, sending the message to each one.

The starting point is the [`GetTopWindow` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633514.aspx), which returns the child window at the top of the Z order. Then, you iterate through the child windows by calling the [`GetNextWindow` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633509.aspx).

MFC actually includes a method that does this, called `SendMessageToDescendants`. You can write the equivalent yourself, and replace `SendMessage` with `PostMessage`, if you'd prefer those semantics.

```
void PostMessageToDescendants(HWND   hwndParent,
                              UINT   uMsg,
                              WPARAM wParam,
                              LPARAM lParam,
                              BOOL   bRecursive)
{
   // Walk through all child windows of the specified parent.
   for (HWND hwndChild = GetTopWindow(hwndParent);
        hwndChild     != NULL;
        hwndChild      = GetNextWindow(hwndChild, GW_HWNDNEXT))
   {
      // Post the message to this window.
      PostMessage(hwndChild, uMsg, wParam, lParam);

      // Then, if necessary, call this function recursively to post the message
      // to all levels of descendant windows.
      if (bRecursive && (GetTopWindow(hwndChild) != NULL))
      {
         PostMessageToDescendants(hwndChild, uMsg, wParam, lParam, bRecursive);
      }
   }
}
```

The arguments are the same as the `PostMessage` function, except for the last one: `bRecursive`. This parameter means just what its name suggests. If `TRUE`, the search of child windows will be *recursive*, so that the message will be posted to all descendants of the parent window (its children, its children's children, etc.). If `FALSE`, the message will be posted only to its immediate children.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and explained answer! `GetNextWindow(hwndChild, GW_HWNDNEXT))` didn't seem to compile, but `GetWindow(hwndChild, GW_HWNDNEXT)` seems to do the intended... I didn't mention before I was using owlnext for the main application MDI window (for historic reasons) and vcl for the child forms. The children have three lines in their constructor to get opened: `tf = new TForm(Owner->Handle); tf->ParentWindow = Owner->Handle; this->PopupParent = tf; `  With your code, `WndProc`doesn't receive the message anymore... maybe it's stuck at `TForm *tf`?

Comment: This answer won't actually send messages to owned dialogs. However, I'm not sure how that would be fixed... would we need to enumerate all top-level windows and filter out the ones that aren't owned by the window in question? A recursive search this way would take much longer because it would have to re-read the entire list every time :| And what about the distinction between topmost and top-level windows that MSDN makes?

Comment: The question was about child windows, @andlabs, nothing about *owned* windows.

Comment: It makes no sense that `GetNextWindow(hwndChild, GW_HWNDNEXT))` wouldn't compile. Something is wrong with your environment. I've used this code hundreds of times.

Comment: @CodyGray  Well, since I use owlnext I have a `window.h` where it is defined as `inline HWND TWindow::GetNextWindow(uint flag) const {   PRECONDITION(GetHandle());   return ::GetWindow(GetHandle(), flag); }` so as a handle, the calling object's handle is taken...  About not receiving any WindowMessages at the child-vcl-dialogs: is the problem that they are actually not childs but owned forms? Is there an adaption of your solution to owned windows ?

Comment: @CodyGray yes, but the term used was "child dialogs", so I'm not sure which word takes precedence.

Answer (score 0):

Cody Gray has given the right solution to the question I asked.

However, as shown in the comments, I asked the wrong question.

My dialogs were vcl `TForms` which were opened by Owl `TWindow`, which means I use the ParentWindow property of the dialogs to get a modal appearance:

```
__fastcall TMyDialog::MyDialog(owl::TWindow* Owner) :TForm(HWND(NULL)){
    tf = new TForm(Owner->Handle); //TForm*, Mainwindow calls this dialog
    tf->ParentWindow = Owner->Handle; // workaround: owl calls vcl
    this->PopupParent = tf; // workaround: owl calls vcl
}
```

So, the result is likely a mix of children and owned dialogs.

What worked for me to get Window Messages to all dialogs that were opened from the main window was this:

```
struct checkMSG{
    HWND handle; UINT msg; WPARAM wparam; LPARAM lparam;
};
checkMSG msgCheck;

BOOL CALLBACK enumWindowsProc(__in  HWND hWnd,__in  LPARAM lParam) {
     HWND owner= ::GetParent(hWnd);
     if(owner==msgCheck.handle)
        ::PostMessage(hWnd, msgCheck.msg, msgCheck.wparam, msgCheck.lparam);
     return TRUE;
}

void SendToAllWindows(HWND handle, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam){
    msgCheck.handle=::GetParent(handle);
    msgCheck.msg=msg;
    msgCheck.wparam= wparam;
    msgCheck.lparam= lparam;
    BOOL enumeratingWindowsSucceeded = ::EnumWindows( enumWindowsProc, NULL );
}
```

- EnumWindows iterates about all windows in all applications.
- To be sure to only get my own application's window's handles, I used a variable `msgCheck` to store the toplevel handle and the message I want to send.
- Now I use `GetParent` which retrieves the *Owner or the Parent* or returns NULL if neither is found.
- In the callback function the stored toplevel handle is compared to the found window's toplevel handle and if they match, the window message is send to the found window's handle